# How do I edit the CSS based on node, page, or placement on page?

Tags: 7, theming

I've been learning how to navigate around and edit my global.css file, but am confused as to how to edit specific elements. I've come across answers to this question that don't specifically describe how to do this

To clarify, say that I have 3 pages on my site titled Red, Blue, and Black. If I want to edit just the h1 headers on page Red, how do I go about doing that? Is there a way to do this without PHP or installing extra modules?

Currently, whenever I try to edit the h1 header on supposed Red page, every single h1 header on my site is updated and edited.

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I honestly couldn't find any answer to my question while I was searching

Answer (score 2):

This isnt a Drupal API question. It's more of a CSS and how does that work in the browser question. That being said there are [docs on how to theme drupal 6 and 7](http://drupal.org/node/388372). Since drupal is a web application they cover topics such as:

1. [Working with CSS](http://drupal.org/node/341246)
2. [Standard Drupal Core Styles and Classes](http://drupal.org/node/388372)

Within (2) it describes the `.node` and `.node-title` CSS classes:

> .node
>
> A wrapper div around all of a node, including its title.
>
> .node-title
>
> The title of the node.

Depending on the theme your using you may or may not have those exact classes, every theme is slightly different. Basically in your theme you want to use Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools to look at the HTML markup and CSS classes and IDs attached to things. You can then target a page or node title, and create a rule to target specific page urls if need be. As an example Drupal page (using [AdaptiveTheme](http://www.drupal.org/project/adaptivetheme) subtheme):

[image]

The `<body>` tag has a million css classes on it including `page-node-2` that specific CSS class would target only this node (by its NID). You can inject other more useful body classes into any theme using hook functions and template files -- but thats beyond this writings scope.

In this case you can also see the node title has an ID of `h1#page-title`

A general CSS rule to target this 1 page's title you could put in `global.css` is `body.page-node-2 h1#page-title { color: red; }`

For your theme it would be the same process:

- examine the body tag in your Theme and find a useful CSS class to specifically target the page(s) with a CSS rule.
- examine the `Section Header` tags within the page to find the exact CSS classes/ids to target just that element as well.

Lastly, I dont think every theme has a `global.css` file ... though most probably do. My exact CSS rules herein will likely not work for your usecase, they're just examples of what you could do. See the documentation pages listed above to better understand Drupal Themeing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using Omega on my site, so there is a global.css file that I'm trying to edit. And how do I find the page node name? How do I find the equivalent of "body.page-node-2" in my css files? And how do I give elements an ID? I'm trying to figure out where the HTML files would be, but to no avail

Comment: you view the source-code in your browser window or using browser developer tools in the browser like Firebug for Firefox. you dont find `body.page-node-2` in your CSS, it's in the rendered HTML.